# How to install Gameranger application on UbuntU?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I new on ubuntu plateform and I want to install gameranger application for Stronghold Crusader.
Can any one please help and guide me.
please mention direct steps or link where installation steps are mentioned.
God bless Ubuntu users.

Comment: Is this a windows game?

Comment: Yes this is a windows game

Comment: Look into the 2 programs wine and playonlinux.